# calculate shipping cost on base on product weight with php

Tags: php

I have to calculate the shipping cost for a product, which has weight. My weight is in grams, that is 1000 grams is 1kg.

Price for the delivery is $2.80 for up to 3kg, and then $0.76 for each additional kg.

Max weight of the delivery is 100kg. I could do if - else, or switch but I would like to come out with some more elegant solution. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: for 3 conditions if\else is fine

Comment: weight in grams, shipping for kilos, can i order 3500g ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want something readable (and guessing you don't want to round):

```
if($weight <3000){
$shipping=2.8;
}elseif ($weight <100000){
$shipping=2.8+(0.00076*($weight-3000));
}else{
$shipping="to heavy";
}

echo $shipping //format $shipping depending on currency
```

Comment: If the weight is 11128, will it calculate in the price and the 128? Or it will calculate it as 12000?

Comment: you havent asked for any rounding

Comment: no, i wanted those 128 grams to be calculated as well.

Comment: that is calculating 11 kg and 128grams or how ever you want to label it

Comment: guess i was right @chiliNUT you can have half my tick, you deserve it

Answer (score 2):

`$cost = $kg <= 100 ? max(array($kg - 3 , 0)) * 0.76 + 2.80 : false`

If `$kg` is less than 100, then:

subtract 3 kg, and

If the result is negative, set it to 0. Multiply that by $0.76 per kg for the remaining kg.

Finally, add the base cost of $2.80 for the initial first "up to 3" kg.

If the base weight is over 100, then return `false` since that is out of range.

in grams:

`$cost = $g <= 100*1000 ? max(array($g - 3*1000 , 0)) * 0.76/1000 + 2.80 : false`

Comment: nice, but not particularly developer friendly

Comment: @Dagon "more elegant" than if else. honestly I see this request as a piecewise mathematical formula, so my answer is how I would naturally see it! An if/else statement may be more verbose, however with detailed commenting I think my answer is still friendly

Comment: I am now testing the solution, I will post here as soon as I finish the testing....

Comment: $cost = $totalWeight <= 100000 ? max(array($totalWeight - 3000 , 0)) * 0.76 + 2.80 : false; - I have make those changes, since my weight is in grams. However, when  $totalWeight = 11126 grams, I get the cost of 6178,56 ?

Comment: you havent said what to do with the weight is fractions of kg,

Comment: ah, if we are in grams, you must also adjust the price rate. $0.76  per kg = $0.00076 per gram

Comment: or maybe he wants rounding

Comment: Now, I get 8,98... According the formula, it calculate price per gram now? Because first 3000 grams are 2.80 then the rest 8000grams *0.76 = 6.8 = 8.88...where he did find that 0.10$, in rest 126grams?

Comment: you gave the weight in kg, then you gave it grams. which do you want? 11126-3000=8126*0.00076=6.17576+2.8=$8.97576

Comment: grams... i added the kg, just to explain...wanted to simplify, and make it mess...

Comment: yeah sorry, i think i confused things more with the g formula. if your unit is g and not kg, your best bet is just to divide by 1000 and plug into the kg formula

Answer (score -2):

try an endless loop like

```
$weight = $weightStart
$costs = 0;
 while ($weight > 0)
 {
 if ($weight < 3){$costs += 2.80;$weightOnce=3} else {$costs = 0.76;$weightOnce = 1;}
 $weight -= $weightOnce;
 }

echo $costs;
```

Comment: i really hope you relies what a bad idea this is